# AngularJS - Expand Elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making FAQ page with AngularJS and I want expand/collapse elements.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="faq" class="">
    <div class="faq-item" collapse>
<div class="expend-element">
    <div class="question">
    <div class="text">Question 1</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="answer">ANSWER 1</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-item" collapse>
<div  class="expend-element">
    <div class="question">
    <div class="text">Question 2</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="answer">ANSWER 2</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-item" collapse>
<div class="expend-element">
    <div class="question">
    <div class="text">Question 3</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="answer">ANSWER 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Directive:

```
return {
    scope: {},
    template:   "<div class='faq-item' ng-click='expend()' ng-class='{ expended: active }'><div ng-transclude></div></div>",
    replace:    true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.active = false;
        scope.expend = function() {
            scope.active = !scope.active;
        };
    }
};
```

This works fine, but it has one problem.
My main aim was to expand was only one element, but this expands all the elements.

How can I make this?